# Issue with face heading for certain todo keyword in orgmode

Tags: org-mode, faces, todo

When I define todo keywords relative to "done" states, the formatting of the heading disappear as below

[image]

Where should I start to look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `org-headline-done`.

> Documentation: Face used to indicate that a headline is DONE. This
> face is only used if `org-fontify-done-headline' is set.  If applies
> to the part of the headline after the DONE keyword.

IOW you have to set `org-fontify-done-headline` to nil.

Comment: BTW you could've called `M-x describe-face` on the "DONE" headline to inspect the face. This would've taken you to the `org-fontify-done-headline` variable.

Comment: Yes, that works ! Thx !